# Doing HTML output in XSLT if based on position

Tags: html, xml, xslt

I am busy with some XSLT stuff, and want to start a new row every 3 items. I thought I could do an if statement and test position mod 3, to find out if I am the first or last cell in my table.

The following if statement does work, but, Copernica (tool I am using XSLT in) doesn't accept the following XSLT. The reason is that the `<tr>` isn't closed within the if statement.

I am looking into a way to handle a product feed splitting into rows after 3 items.

```
<xsl:if test="position() mod 3 = 1">
<tr>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you would use another `<xsl:if/>` later in your code to close the `<tr/>`. Unfortunately while this would be valid in another programming language it can't be with xslt.

XSLT is **not** a **procedural or imperative language** so don't use it as one. Instead you can do something like this :

```
<xsl:template match="element[position() mod 3 = 1]">
  <tr>
   <xsl:apply-templates mode="single" select=".|following-sibling::element[not(position() > 2)]"
   />
  </tr>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="element" mode="single">
  <td>
    <!--your stuff between rows here-->
  </td>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="element[not(position() mod 3 = 1)]"/>
```

So this basically creates a tr every three rows and in addition calls another template to process elements which are in between those rows. "element" should be the element you want to process.

Comment: +1 good answer. Should that be `not(position() >=3)` though, instead of `> 3`? Seems like you're including three following siblings in addition to self.

Comment: Good answer, but I think it's unnecessarily strong to suggest that XSLT is not a programming language. It's certainly not a *procedural* or *imperative* language, but it must be a *programming* language. What else would you call it?

Comment: @lwburk Gee... I was paraphrasing for brevity, but fine... it's "fixed" now (sometimes I think it's a competition to see who can be the most pedantic)

Comment: @FailedDev - Precision and pedantry are sometimes the same thing and often not. It was a good answer, anyway.

Answer (score 2):

If Copernica accepted that XSLT, it would be wrong. XSLT is XML, and XML has to be strictly hierarchical. An `<xsl:if>` element cannot contain a start tag like `<tr>` without a matching end tag `</tr>` in the same `<xsl:if>` element. To put it another way, an XSLT stylesheet is not a freeform stream of start and end tags; it's a stream of start and end tags that express a *tree structure* of nodes. `<a> <b> </a>` does not express a tree structure, even if you have a `</b>` later. Think of start/end tags like parentheses:

```
(1 * [2 + 3)]
```

is not grammatical.

@FailedDev is right that you cannot treat XSLT as a *procedural* programming language. You cannot assume that elements will be processed in a particular order. Rather than thinking "I need to start a new row every three items" (a procedural, one-after-another concept), you need to conceive of it as "I need to group the items in groups of three, with a row containing each group."

I can't think of a better implementation of that than @FailedDev's in XSLT 1.0, so I won't offer one. In XSLT 2.0, you can use

```
  <xsl:for-each-group group-starting-with="element[position() mod 3 = 1]">
    <tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()" />
    </tr>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
```

...

```
<xsl:template match="element">
   <!-- your stuff between rows here -->
</xsl:template>
```